# Displaying cv2 Mat in the GDB debugger

Tags: c++, opencv

I am debugging a function written in C++ for Python in GDB. The function makes use of the OpenCV. Is it possible to display the value of the OpenCV Mat in the GDB debugger?

For Mat yp, that is only what I get:

```
(gdb) print(yp) 

$48 = {flags = 1124024325, dims = 2, rows = 1, cols = 100, 
  data = 0x7fff979c9530 "", refcount = 0x7fff979c96c0, 
  datastart = 0x7fff979c9530 "", dataend = 0x7fff979c96c0 "\001", 
  datalimit = 0x7fff979c96c0 "\001", allocator = 0x0, size = {
p = 0x7fffffff9ab8}, step = {p = 0x7fffffff9b00, buf = {400, 4}}}

(gdb) print(yp.at<float>(0,1))
Cannot evaluate function -- may be inlined
```

Comment: have a look at [ccv module](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/d7/dcf/tutorial_cvv_introduction.html) and [this](https://github.com/beenfrog/gdb-opencv-viewer)

Comment: Might as well refer to [this plugin](https://github.com/OpenImageDebugger/OpenImageDebugger), maybe it will work for you.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the following command to print yp.data as an array of 200 floats noting that 200 = rows * cols * dims:
`(gdb) print *(float *)yp.data@200`

Here I rely on the fact that the data member of cv::Mat is a pointer to a data buffer.  This should work with OpenCV 2.x, 3.x and 4.x assuming a default stride (step size) of 1.

Answer (score 1):

If you use GDB inside CLion you can utilize the OpenCV Image Viewer plugin, which displays matrices while debugging just on click.

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14371-opencv-image-viewer

[image]

Disclaimer: I'm an author of this plugin